# Are there examples where introducing clusters of binary variables provides a benefit for solving?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, integer-programming, binary-variable, knapsack

I have a larger model with a large number of binary variables among many others. For the purpose of this question, consider the effect that the binary variables impose on the model to be similar to that of a Knapsack. The variable considers to take a certain item or not and in general taking an item provides a certain benefit. However, due to the rest of the model, the change is of course more complex. The overall size and complexity of the model makes it quite difficult to identify the right items to be taken, so I introduced some dependencies among the variables that may alter the optimal solution, but which led me to the idea of adding further variables and dependencies that do not affect the optimal solution. I was wondering on the effect of solving the model by introducing additional artificial binary variables that cluster the actual variables, by means of logical-or connections. More concretely, let's consider these two models

$$
\max c^T \cdot x \\
\text{s.t. } w^T \cdot x \leq W \\
x_i \in \{0, 1\}
$$

and

$$
\max c^T \cdot x \\
\text{s.t. } w^T \cdot x \leq W \\
y_k \geq x_i \quad \forall \, k, i \in H_k \\
y_k \leq \sum_{i \in H_k} x_i \\
x_i \in \{0, 1\} \\
y_k \in \{0, 1\}
$$

Can there be a positive effect for solving the second model at all? And if yes, what would be the conditions (supposedly concerning $H_k$, but also the branching strategy of the solver) for such a positive effect? Or would presolve just eliminate all $y_k$ anyway?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the "cluster idea". If I understand you correctly, you want to say that if $x_i=1$ then we should pick at least one item from $H_k$. But you also have that the index $i$ is in $H_k$. So, if we pick item $i$ we have already picked and item from $H_k$ and the constraint seem redundant.

Comment: Yes the constraint is redundant. The idea is this, what if the solver branches on y = 0 sometimes, it is then not be able to set any of the xi to 1, so it should achieve a leaf sooner. Branching on x does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a presolver would eliminate the $y_k$ would depend on how the presolver was programmed. Assuming the variables survived presolve, giving the $y_k$ higher priority than the $x_i$ in branching would be similar to using a custom branching scheme in which early nodes are partitioned using $$\sum_{i\in H_k} x_i \ge 1$$ and $$\sum_{i\in H_k} x_i \le 0$$for some $k$. (I said "similar" rather than "identical" because I'm not sure all solvers would treat branching priorities as absolute, whereas you would presumably have full control over a custom branching scheme.)

Whether it would help is an empirical question. In a simple knapsack problem, I would be surprised if it did, but in a more complex model it perhaps might be productive *if* the variable sets were defined in such a way that knowing at least one $x_i$ took value 1 for $i\in H_k$ did something significant in reducing the solution space (tightened the bound significantly, forced other variables to be either 0 or 1, ...).

I have to disagree with the contention that the added binary variables and constraints "may result in loss of the optimal solution". At least as you implemented them in the example, the projection onto the $x$ space of the solution space of the expanded model is the same as the solution space of the original model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, probably investigating in cusom branching priorities is more fruitful than to hope that the solver figures out it can branch more effectively on y than on x. It seems like I have to try it ;-) I updated the answer to clarify that the solution space change was due to the dependencies I added into my real model which only led me to this question. I agree that the solution space of the first model given here is a subset of the solution space given in the expanded model.